# How to Create Date Incrementing Trigger in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I'm not very experienced in Postgresql, and in a personal project I have the table column `ID` (Primary Key) being a date with format `yyyy-mm-dd`, like this

```
ID
---
2020-07-12
2020-07-13
2020-07-14
```

I want to create a trigger so that `ID` value gets automatically incremented (based on latest ID value) when a new record is inserted.  Also what is the recommended data type for the column `ID` in this case?

**My goal**
The table stores Daily Report summaries, it's already known that new record will be the next day and I want to eliminate the need to specify the report's Date manually.
Report data is inserted using service call to application, and reducing the payload params to the minimum is important.

Comment: Incremented based on what? The latest date in the table?

Comment: Yes, latest ID value.

Comment: *Don't* use a date as an auto-incrementing PK. It's too coarse-grained for that. As for using `MAX+1` to generate new key values, it's a recipe for disaster - deletions can easily lead to the generation of duplicate keys, corrupting foreign key relations. The `SELECT MAX(ID)+1` operation has to take excessive locks  to calculate that MAX value, thus reducing scaleability

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the advice, I'll consider changing the table design. Is it possible at all to setup such trigger for another columns, let's say `Date` so I don't have to manually populate it myself on every new insert?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Calendar table perhaps? It's far easier to calculate eg 50 years of dates using a query and store them into the new table, with the `Date` column acting as a regular PK. A 50 year Calendar table takes very little space

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? You're describing what you think the solution would look like, not the problem. If you want a Calendar table, you can use one of the myriad scripts available. If you want audit columns (eg Created, Updated) you can use simple triggers to store the current timestamp on INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: Please check the question again, I added 'My Goal' paragraph.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you insert many rows on the same day?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Multiple insertions will create subsequent records each one has the new Date (next day).

Comment: So if I insert 100 rows _today_ they will have date values from `2020-07-15` to `2020-10-23`? That sounds like a really strange behaviour to me. If the table stores "daily report summaries" how can you insert a summary for the future?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If a Date value is provided in the request it means 'update the existing record with this date', if not Date value was specified this means 'create new record by increment latest date's value'.

Comment: So your summary code can predict the future, cool. How do you know the "predicted summary" for the first row is for tomorrow and not for next week's thursday? I also can't possibly imagine how a single date value (that you already supply  if you want to make an update) can increase the payload size to an extent that it's a problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There will be only a new service request every day if system is up-to-date, or I might come back after 5 days and insert the reports I missed for the prev 5 days to catch-up .. it's kinda personal side project.

Comment: Then declare the column with a default value of `current_date` and don't provide a value during insert

Comment: Will try that, thank you!

Comment: It appears you have a built in failure. You say it  "already known that new record will be the next day" but later indicate you may have a gap is days. How do you guarantee data for the missed days hit **in the proper order**; how do you guarantee that day 6 doesn't hit the database **before** the missed days. You cannot specify the date of the missed days as that would require updating non-existing days.  Also if its for the next day perhaps default needs to be current_day + 1; depending upon the time-of-day it is run of course.